why in most OS the first virtual page in any process with addresses 0:1000 is protected by OS
i understand that NULL pointer has special meaning and if pointer points to virtual address 0 then it will be same. So this is main reason of protection on first virtual page?
i tried to map the memory with fixed virtual addresses

I'm not sure there's a deep reason behind it, besides "code that accesses a pointer of all zeros is usually wrong." The best thing to do in that case is to stop the process that did it, and the easiest way to stop a process in that case is to mark the first page as non readable and non writable.

The only reason is to catch common programming errors involving uninitialized pointers. Doing so, makes a pointer to 0 point to nothing (NULL, NIL). Keep in mind that most operating systems allow users to map the first logical memory page to the address space if they really want to do so.

Well, null dereference can arise from many other types of bugs besides uninitialized pointers.  But I see your point.
